# WPF - How to stop TextBox from autosizing?

Tags: wpf, textbox, grid, autosize

I have a textbox in my visual tree as follows..

- `Window`

  - `Grid`

    - `ListBox`

      - `ItemTemplate`

        - `DataTemplate`

          - `Grid`

            - `Grid`

              - `Textbox`...

The textbox is defined as..

```
<TextBox Height="Auto" 
         Text="{Binding Path=LyricsForDisplay}" 
         MinHeight="50" 
         MaxHeight="400"  
         Visibility="Visible" 
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         IsReadOnly="True" 
         AllowDrop="False" 
         TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
</TextBox>
```

When long text is added to the bound variable (LyricsForDisplay) all of the items in the listbox expand their textboxes/grids width's to allow for the entire string to be seen if you use the scrollbar on bottom that appears...

What I would like to do is make it so the boxes/grids only resize if the user stretches the window .. NOT when a long text is entered (it could just wrap around..)

Does anyone know how to obtain the functionality?

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, the regular TextBox doesn't allow autoresize to fit the parent but NOT autoresize when the text doesn't fit.

To solve this problem, you can use a custom TextBox that reports a desired (0, 0) size. It's an ugly hack, but it works.

In your .xaml.cs file:

```
public class TextBoxThatDoesntResizeWithText : TextBox
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        return new Size(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Then, in your .xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.YourWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace">
        ...
        <local:TextBoxThatDoesntResizeWithText Height="Auto" 
                                               Text="{Binding Path=LyricsForDisplay}" 
                                               MinHeight="50" 
                                               MaxHeight="400"  
                                               Visibility="Visible" 
                                               VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                               IsReadOnly="True" 
                                               AllowDrop="False" 
                                               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
        </local:TextBoxThatDoesntResizeWithText>
        ...
</Window>
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me! This feels like behaviour which should be part of the standard control. Cheers, @ajarov, saved me a lot of time spinning my wheels!

Comment: Helped me as well! Easy solution, even though a bit 'hacky', thanks!

Comment: Solved my problem too, after a lot of hair-tearing. In recent versions of C# the function can be a one-liner: `protected override Size MeasureOverride( Size constraint ) => Size.Empty;`

Answer (score 10):

The following works:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox1"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Notice the use of `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` and `TextWrapping="Wrap"`.

Answer (score 4):

*Something* needs to contrain the horizontal width available to the TextBoxes, in this case you want to stop the `ListBox` from growing horizontally indefinitely:

```
<ListBox HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

Comment: "The property 'HorizontalScrollBarVisility' was not found in type 'ListBox'."

Comment: It's `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` actually.

Answer (score 2):

two change the code:
1- add border tag with your grid.column and grid.row size that you are neads.
2- width and height of textbox set to it.
sample:

```
 <Border x:Name="b" Margin="5"/>


  <TextBox Height="Auto" 
             Text="{Binding Path=LyricsForDisplay}" 
             MinHeight="50" 
             Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=b}" 
             Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=b}" 
             Visibility="Visible" 
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
             IsReadOnly="True" 
             AllowDrop="False" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap">
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the the **MaxWidth** Property in Your Textbox

```
<TextBox Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Path=LyricsForDisplay}" MinHeight="50" MaxHeight="400"  Visibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxWidth="100" IsReadOnly="True" AllowDrop="False" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">                            </TextBox>
```