# Limit width of TextBox to the width of the ListView that contains it

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, textbox

I am working on a MVVM app (the examples here are not very MVVM though, its just a mockup).

I have a `ListView`, that binds to a collection of `TextItemViewModel` instances, the view for these are defined in `TextItemView`. Each `TextItemView` contains a `Grid` with one `Auto` column and on `*` column to fill. The fill column contains a `TextBox` where the user can enter text.

I want the `TextItemView`s to fill the horizontal space of the `ListView` (this works), like so:

[image]

However, when a user enters long text in a box, I want it to expand in `Height` but not in `Width`. At the moment, the `Width` increases and the `ListView` gets a scrollbar, like so:

[image]

My `ListView` code looks like this: (I've taken out the MVVM Binding code and set the `ItemsSource` in the code-behind for this example)

```
<ListView Name="listview"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          Margin="5"
          MinHeight="50"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

And my `TextItemView` code looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Content="SomeButton"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"                
            Margin="5"
            Grid.Column="0" />

    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=NoteText}"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             AcceptsReturn="True"
             AcceptsTab="True"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                 
             Margin="5"                 
             Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Can anyone advise me on how to force the `TextItemView` to fill the width of the `ListView` (as it does), but to then wrap the `TextBox` and expand `TextItemView` in `Height` when the `TextBox` fills up?

Answer (score 13):

OK I got this now thanks to [WPF - How to stop TextBox from autosizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465646/wpf-how-to-stop-textbox-from-autosizing)

Trick is to add the following to `ListView` definition:

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```